# Is there a reason behind the number of bit rotations used in SHA-256?

Tags: sha-256

**SHA-256** uses the following bitwise functions during the hash algorithm:

$$\begin{align*}
\Sigma_0^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{ 2}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{13}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{22}(x)\\
\Sigma_1^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{ 6}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{11}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{25}(x)\\
\sigma_0^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{ 7}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{18}(x)\oplus\operatorname{SHR}^{ 3}(x)\\
\sigma_1^{\{256\}}(x)&=\operatorname{ROTR}^{17}(x)\oplus\operatorname{ROTR}^{19}(x)\oplus\operatorname{SHR}^{10}(x)\end{align*}$$

Is there are reason behind the **number of circular right shifts (ROTR)** each of these functions use? I'm guessing its to try and "scramble" the bits as much as possible, but why for example does `Σ0` use rotations of `2`, `13`, and `22`?

Is there an actual reason, or are they arbitrary?

I notice each function uses a *prime* number for at least one of their rotations, but aside from that I haven't been able to find a reason for the numbers. The specification doesn't seem to explain why.

Comment: In short; Years of experience from SHA-0 and SHA-1.

Comment: very related https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17620/significance-of-rotation-constants-in-sha-512?rq=1